# how to write a file path so that it works on another computer with the same file elsewhere?

Tags: python, file, path

I tried to write a command in python to call the file with the filename only(code below), but then I got an error `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spam.csv' "`(this file is on my computer). How I can fix it? I don't want to write all file's path because this code will be checked on the other computer with other files location.

```
with open(r'spam.csv') as file:
 reader = csv.reader(file)
 spam_list = [row[0] for row in reader]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the file is in the same folder as the script. You can construct the path to the data file dynamically. You just have to know that `__file__` contains the full path to the script (including the filename of the script).

Then you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from Pythons standard library to construct the path to your file. `pathlib.Path(__file__)` is the script itself. `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent` is the parent of the script: the folder where the script is.

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'spam.csv'

with open(path) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    spam_list = [row[0] for row in reader]
```

If your file is e.g. in a subfolder "data" you can use

```
path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'data' / 'spam.csv'
```

Comment: I wrote it with your part of code and there are errors: "NameError: name '__file__' is not defined." and " NameError: name 'path' is not defined"

Comment: How do you run your script? It won't work if you just type these lines in an interactive interpreter because there is no file. But if you call it on the command line, as one normally does, `__file__` must be defined.